Why did my ssh port forwarding not work?
I have this port forwarding set up at my home:

Fedora 39 server with sshd set up and firewall disabled.
Linksys WRT32X router using OpenWRT 23.05.x connected to a cable modem (routing capable,
but used in bridge mode) for net.
32X has a port forwarding rule on port 23456 to port 22 on the Fedora box.

This is meant to be a FTP over ssh setup, but I can use it like real ssh for management etc.
A couple days ago it all stopped working, it keeps timing out. From the Fedora box logs it looks like it never saw any login attempts coming.
For testing from outside my LAN I have my phone as wifi hotspot.
ssh to my laptop using a different forwarded port on the router worked.
Everything works inside my LAN.
Did a few updates on F39 including the kernel. While testing on the router its firewall was restarted a few times.
If it matters, it seems like ISP has IPv6 support, so I enabled it, but all connections to F39 ssh server have to be done via IPv4, because an ipv6 address is too long to manually enter.
As a last ditch effort I also tried changing the port on the router (ie. use 24680 -> 22 instead) and it still doesn't work.
So the individual parts work, but when put together it doesn't. I have no idea why and am at my wits end.

has your public IP address changed?

... and ... has the fedora box IP address changed?
